# Trying to make a mex file for octave but I am getting errors

Tags: gnome, matlab, octave

```
octave-3.2.4:1> mkoctfile --mex myhello.c
sh: 1: /usr/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.4: not found
warning: unable to find mkoctfile in expected location: `/usr/bin/mkoctfile-3.2.4'
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
```

I have searched for mkoctfile and i found it in this path

`/usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/miscellaneous/mkoctfile.m`

Please tell me what I should do to create mex file

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that header files were missing . So I installed header files from Ubuntu software center . Just type `mkoctfile` in search and install `Header files  for the GNU octave language (3.2 branch)` 
now i can compile `.mex` files using the command

```
mkoctfile --mex myhello.c
```